# Stalks of Structure Sheaf of a Closed Discrete Subscheme are Fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme, $a$ a closed point of $X$ considered as a reduced closed subscheme $\{a\} := Z$ of $X$ and let $\alpha \subset \mathcal{O}_X$ the corresponding ideal sheaf.

So we have the exact sequence

$0 \to  \alpha \to  \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Z$

Obviously $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is a skyscraper sheaf.
I read that

\begin{align}
\mathcal{O}_{Z,x} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                \kappa(a) = \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/ m_a, & \hspace{5mm} \text{if }x=a \\
                0 & \hspace{5mm} \text{else} \\
                 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

My quetion is why $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ is a ***field*** at $x=a$.

Or more generally: If $Z = \{z_1, ... z_n\}$ is a discrete set of closed points why for their skyscraper structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_Z$ the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ for each $x = z_i$ is a field?

Comment: This can be checked locally.  Can you prove the corresponding commutative algebra statement?

Comment: By considering the affine case? So because $Z$ is a zero dimensional top space, it's global section ring has Krull dimension zero, is identical with it's stalk, therefore is local and reduced. So $(0)$ is the unique max ideal of it, so it's a field, right? Or do you mean another argument?

Comment: I worry you're missing something important, but that we're not answering it.  As Eric has written out, the solution to you question is a rather trivial chase of definitions once you localize to the affine case.  One thing that strikes me about your question is that you wrote $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z$ rather than $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$, and also that you didn't put $\rightarrow 0$ on your exact sequence.  I somehow feel that these omissions point more towards the heart of your question than the answers you've received so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question only depends on an open neighborhood of $a$, so we may assume $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$ is affine, and our sheaves are determined by their global sections as $R$-modules.  Then since $a$ is a closed point, it is a maximal ideal of $R$, and that ideal is exactly $\alpha(X)$.  So $\mathcal{O}_Z(X)=R/\alpha(X)$ is the quotient of $R$ by a maximal ideal, which is a field.  Since $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is a skyscraper sheaf at $a$, its global sections are the same as its stalk at $a$, so $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ is a field.  (Or, the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ is just the localization of $R/\alpha(X)$ with respect to the maximal ideal $\alpha(X)$, but $R\setminus\alpha(X)$ already acts on $R/\alpha(X)$ by units so this does not change it.)

The more general question is exactly the same, since to compute $\mathcal{O}_{Z,z_i}$ you can choose an affine open neighborhood that contains $z_i$ and no other points of $Z$.